# fullcalendar updateEvent updates all the events not the target one

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to update the event that I edited but `.fullCalendar('updateEvent', res.old)` just updated all events and apply the `res.old` to them, I don't know why.
Thanks for helping in advance and sorry for my poor English

Comment: It will be better if you provide basic code detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code it's a bit of a guess but the docs say:

```
event must be the original Event Object for an event, not merely a reconstructed object. 
The original Event Object can obtained by callbacks such as eventClick, or by the clientEvents method.
```

You probably don't give an original event back to the function, if you provide some code I'll look into it for you.

Comment: the `res.old` is the response of a JQuery POST, it consists of original attributes `_start` `_end` `start` `end` `allDay` `id` and my own attributes `recurrence_count` and so on, will they cause any problems? If I use `refetchEvent` , it performs well.

Comment: Could you add a plunkr ?

Comment: I'm so sorry that the proxy I use can not connect to plunkr. here is some of my codes `res.old._start = data._start;
                        res.old._end = data._end;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', res.old);` and after `updateEvent`, `data` is the data of the target at the beginning when I clicked it. All events become the same as the earliest one

Comment: A jsbin is fine too, it's nice if I could fiddle around with the code a bit

Comment: The only thing I can think if is that res.old isn't an actual calendar event, could you provide a minimal working testcase ?

Comment: Sorry I can't... It needs some codes wrote by others and I can not get them. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I've got the problem. It's because the `id` I got is `Number` while `fullcalendar` need is `String`